# How to get unique values from 1 field returning all fields

Tags: mysql

Im Trying to get 10 results based on the highest score where description is unique.

So these 10 results should not contain records with the same description.

The Query that needs modification to return unique values in column `description`
selecting all field:

```
`SELECT * FROM datafeeds 
WHERE device_id = 1 
ORDER BY score 
LIMIT 10;`
```

Comment: Is laravel important here? What is your goal with this query? What are your current indexes? Your query is slow, because the second condition makes no sense, but MySQL is happy to calculate it for you. (Well, it basically filters out all `NULL` values, but isn't `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` a better way to do so?)

Comment: Currently no indexes, im at the point of adding them.
The second condition was used to return only unique values from the description field. When just using `GROUP BY description` instead of `AND description IN (
   SELECT description 
   FROM datafeeds 
   GROUP BY description)` its really slow.

Comment: OK, but what is the problem. What this query should solve? You sent us a query whit no information about the environment and it's goal. Show some effort, describe your problem (no, the query is slow is not your root problem). Why do you think, that any indexes will solve any speed related issues? They can slow down queries in some cases. So step back, rephrase your question and give us a proper question. (Marked as unclear what you are asking).

Comment: @pred as stated above "Im Trying to get 10 results based on the highest score where description is unique" But this query i have is really slow, so i  searched how to speed it up and came  across indexing, so i asked how to index for this query. Does this clear things up for you?

Comment: What 'unique' means? Only one row with that description? What if there are 2 or more rows with the same description?

Comment: Then i don't want them returned. You think indexing is the way to go?

Comment: You don't want to display any of them or just the 'second' one. If you want to display only one of the duplicated descriptions, then how do you want to determine which record should be displayed?

Comment: there is a column named 'score', the highest score needs to be picked, for example the first 5 highest scores have the same description, then i only want 1 of those 5.

Comment: ok, what if 2 of them have the same score AND the same description?

Comment: one of both would be okay then. Doesnt matter if its the first second or third, because they would be the same to me

Comment: OK, now please give us a table structure. (the result of the `show create table` for example)

Comment: Actually it would be nice if you would take the time and add the information you gave me to the post via editing it, and rephrase your question to represent your actual problem. (Just a note, your query will not give you the result what you described to me in the comments above.)

Comment: http://imgur.com/bO5WnpD

This is the table structure

Comment: Can u tell me how this query would differ from what i explained?

Comment: Your query will return all non-null descriptions and will never filter duplicates. It is pure luck if you got the correct results. Essentially you said to mysql: get all the descriptions from my table, then return all results which has one of them. Which is in short: give me all records which has a non null description. After this, order them by score, then return the first 10. the `IN` returns ALL records matching ANY of the values listed in the predicate or returned by a subquery.

Comment: Okay, think that it slowed the query down also? I removed it from the query now it runs fast, but i get duplicate records with same description. Do you know how to achieve getting unique values from description column. I need all fields from the selected rows, but no duplicates in description

Comment: If you get different result after removing the IN condition (and only the IN condition), then the query you shared with us is not the query you are actually using in your application. (assuming, there are no NULLs in the description field). And yes, I know how to get something which may satisfy your need, but it is not an answer to this question in this form. So either edit your question, include all information what we may need or delete this question and create a new one with the required info. This may help to write a good question: [ask]

Comment: @pred question is edited taking in new information, got closer to the solution, thanks already!

Comment: There you go if I understood you correctly. Please share essential info in the future. I would close this question because of the lack of information, most probably this is a duplicate too. In the future, please use the search feature, and when you can't find an answer, gather all information and describe your problem properly. This discussion took about an hour, which would cost about 150-300 EUR on the market. The more effort you show, the faster and the more accurate answer you get. Keep this in mind :)

Comment: I am curious if the queries we gave you are helped or not to solve your problem...

Comment: Hi @pred, it did help me to get me in the right direction, im really close to the solution. Thank you very much for your time, appreciatie it!

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key and order by it. It really helps.

Comment: There is no such thing in MySQL. You can not set the order of the PK (you can in the query, but it is not implemented -> has no effect).

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it step by step:

First get the list of the descriptions you are interested in with an id from your table:

```
SELECT
  MAX(score) as max_score,
  MAX(id) as last_id,
  description
FROM
  datafeeds 
WHERE
  device_id = 1
GROUP BY
  description
ORDER BY
  MAX(score) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Now, you have a list of descriptions, lets grab all the columns for them:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  datafeeds
WHERE
  id IN (
    SELECT
      MAX(id) as last_id
    FROM
      datafeeds 
    WHERE
      device_id = 1
    GROUP BY
      description
    ORDER BY
      MAX(score) DESC
    LIMIT 10
);
```

The above query may give you an error, which states that `LIMIT` is not supported...

A hack like this may help:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  datafeeds
WHERE
  id IN (
    SELECT last_id FROM (
      SELECT
        MAX(id) as last_id
      FROM
        datafeeds 
      WHERE
        device_id = 1
      GROUP BY
        description
      ORDER BY
        MAX(score) DESC
      LIMIT 10
  ) AS X
);
```

Or a join to a subquery

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT last_id FROM (
      SELECT
        MAX(id) as last_id
      FROM
        datafeeds 
      WHERE
        device_id = 1
      GROUP BY
        description
      ORDER BY
        MAX(score) DESC
      LIMIT 10
  ) X
  INNER JOIN datafeeds DF
    ON X.last_id = DF.id
;
```

An index on the `description` column could help, or you can create a covering index using the following fields: `description`, `device_id`, `score`, `id`.

You may get better results if you use the `score` or `device_id` as the first column in the index. This depends on the data what we don't know.

Please note that

1. grouping on a `text` column is slow and will be slow even with indexes
2. an index on a `text` column will almost double the storage requirements of the table

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed there is no need to use Subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `datafeeds` 
WHERE `device_id` = 1
 GROUP BY `description
ORDER BY `score` 
LIMIT 10';
```

Comment: the subquery is used to get unique values from the description column. I think this is the way to do it?

Comment: This produces indeterminate results for non-aggregated columns

Comment: May i know what is wrong with this query @ strawberry

Comment: @Assen: the problem with the query is that the OP can not describe their problem, so your query (and all answers) are just guessing. Just search for `The XY problem`.

Comment: @Pred I have noticed he is using sub query which is not usefull and slow down the performace ...so, this wil be answer for his question

Comment: @Assen I did not say, that your answer is wrong. My main point is that the question is wrong, so we can not answer it properly. (Btw, if I really want to find something, you may have to add a `description IS NOT NULL` condition). But again, my point is that you can not answer a question properly which is essentially wrong.

Comment: Yeah Okay @ Pred..He is new user so, i helped him .. thank you

Comment: Thanks to all for helping :)